# how to exec() in a for loop? in C

Tags: c, linux, command, exec

I'm trying to implement the cat command invoking the exec() function and saving the output of it in a tmp file. My issue is that I know that after invoking exec() anything afterwards will be ignore, therefore there's no point of looping the exec().

If I have N number of arguments to pass to the main program, how can I loop exec() in order to read all arguments?

Note: Using system() is not a choice for me, that's how the assignment is.

Right now I have the following code in a not very elegant way:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{
    int fd;
    char filename[] = "tmp.txt";

    fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fd, 1);   // make stdout go to file
    dup2(fd, 2);   // make stderr go to file                
    close(fd);

    execl("/bin/cat", argv[0], argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], NULL);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: you mean pass, not parse, right?

Comment: And `execv()` should do just what you want. https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv

Comment: @MarkYisri, you are right, my misspelling.

Comment: Your code actually looks pretty good, you just have the wrong `exec` function.

Comment: Your code does not **implement** `cat`, but just runs it.

Comment: @Olaf I believe that the sentence "..trying to implement the cat command invoking the exec() function..." it's quite self explanatory. Sorry but I don't see the point of your comment.

Comment: There is a clear distinction between "to implement" and "to call/execute". For the first it is indeed irritating why you would use one of the `exec()` functions. But then you were not the first having major missunderstanding what certain functions do (and what not). Being clear about what one wants and does is the basis of successful communication.

Comment: @krm you might want to change the title of the question because my answer does not exactly answer the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`execv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) (standard library function):

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

Which will accept an argv. For standard compliance, make sure that `argv[0] == path`.

So, here's your code, rewritten:

```
int main( int argc,char *argv[] )
{
    int fd;
    char filename[] = "tmp.txt";

    fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fd, 1);   // make stdout go to file
    dup2(fd, 2);   // make stderr go to file                
    close(fd);
    execv("/bin/cat", (char *[]) { "/bin/cat", NULL });
    return(0);
}
```